# using browser's cookies to save webApplication data

Tags: java, gwt, httpcookie

In my GWT Web Application I want to save some of my app-s data in user's browser cookies. Such as Layout condition, that are changing by user. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: iam tryng gwt lcoal storage.

Comment: Do consider performance impact for your get/post calls as they transmit cookie data on every call!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simple! look at: 
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/Cookies.html

Also take a look at Window object

Answer (score 0):

In GWT there is a class

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Cookies;
```

Is it what you are looking for

```
//get  cookie with name of the cookie
    String msg = Cookies.getCookie("cookiename");


    //set cookie  with name 

    Cookies.setCookie("cookiename",msg);
```

Remeber cookie with no value returns null .